# How to check if key of object in array has specific value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check if an object in an array has a specific Date value in the following data format?

I have an array like this for example

```
[
  {
    date: '2020-05-03',
    items: [{}...]
  },
  ...
]

-> In the above array, I want to check if any object in the array has '2020-05-03' as the date value.
```

And I want to find out if an object with Date is ??

I tried the following, but this only confirms that it has a 'date' as the key, and I couldn't compare values.

```
const existsDate = _.find(prev, 'date');
```

I also want to push an item to the items of the object containing that date if a date already exists.

If not, i need to create a new date object.

Comment: What have you already tried? It's a good idea to include what you've already tried doing to overcome this, and what problems you're facing. This will make your question more focused and easier to answer concisely. Please take the [Tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: use `filter` or `find`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Array.prototype.find` and do a string comparison

```
var arr = [
  {
    date: '2020-05-03',
    items: [{}...]
  },
]

const obj = arr.find(item => item.data === '2020-05-03');
```

EDIT: Since you want to update the existing array, you would need to make use of slice with findIndex to update array

```
var arr = [
      {
        date: '2020-05-03',
        items: [{}...]
      },
    ]
    const newItem = {};
    const index= arr.findIndex(item => item.data === '2020-05-03');
    if(index > -1) {
       arr = [...arr.slice(0, index), {...arr[index], items: arr[index].items.concat(newItems), ...arr.slice(index + 1)}
    } else {
      arr.push({data: new Date(), items: [newItem]})
    }
```

Comment: I registered additional questions with my attempts. Thank you for checking!

Comment: @COLEAN Updated myanswer for your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use, Array [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get/check the required conditions, for example:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    date: '2020-05-03',
    items: [{}]
  },
  {
    date: '2020-05-02',
    items: [{}]
  }
]

function checkAndAdd(date) {
  const res = arr.find(ob => ob.date === date);
  // console.log(res);
  // based on the added comments.
  // if date is found, push something to the items, list:
  if (res) {
    res.items.push('Hello');
  } else {
    arr.push({
      date,
      items: [{}]
    })
  }
  
  console.log('finalArray', arr);

}

checkAndAdd('2020-05-03');
checkAndAdd('2020-05-06');
```

Comment: I registered additional questions with my attempts. Thank you for checking!

Comment: @COLEAN Your question isn't much clear to me, can you try reframing ut?

Comment: @COLEAN: Updated the answer, as far as I understood the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you caan use filter or find function

```
let arr = [
    {data:'2020-05-23'},
    {data:'2020-06-23'},
    {data:'2020-07-23'}
]

let find = arr.find( (val) => val.data == '2020-06-23')

console.log(find)
```

Comment: I registered additional questions with my attempts. Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking to do but his code iterates through the array of objects and checks against the date variable. It outputs the index (i).

```
let date = "2020-05-03"

const array = [

{   date: "2020-05-01"   },   
{   date: "2020-05-02"   },   
{   date: "2020-05-03",   }, 

]


for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++) {   
    if(array[i].date === date) {
        console.log(i);   } 
    else {
        console.log("Date not in array");   
    } 
}
```